# Web fonts do not load in Firefox and Internet Explorer on first page

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, fonts

I have a site built on Expression Engine, and while everything is working fine in Google Chrome and Safari, I'm having problems with web fonts in Internet Explorer and Firefox. The issue is that the fonts won't display when you first visit the website. If you load a different page, the fonts do display, and everything is fine after that. However, if you clear the browser's cache and return to the website, the problem occurs again.

I've tried everything from loading the fonts locally to making sure the font styles are loaded right at the top of the page.

Here is a look at the first few lines of my CSS template, which is loaded right at the beginning of the html file, but in a "header" template. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide! The website in question is: http://bayareafellowship.com

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'montserratregular';
   src: url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot');
   src: url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserratregular') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'leaguegothic-regular-webfont';
   src: url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot');
   src: url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.svg#leaguegothic-regular-webfontregular') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

.montserratregular {
   font-family: 'montserratregular';
}

.leaguegothic-regular-webfont {
   font-family: 'leaguegothic-regular-webfont';
}

.montserratbold {
   font-family: 'monteserratbold';
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE specifically? Hit F12. Switch to the Console tab. Does the page have an error message showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out to be a server issue, with the font files not being recognized as being on the same server. This is the piece of code that solved everything for me, placed in the .htaccess file.

```
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
```

I'm still having issues with FOUT, but that's another story for another day. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem where IE ignored the font occasionally. The problem then was that the font-family name I used contained too many characters for IE, but worked fine for all the other browsers.

Try shorten down the names, especially `'leaguegothic-regular-webfont'`. Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for the the response!

The long font-family name was actually an attempt at matching the web font family name. The original was 'league_gothic' and the bug still occurred.